# Monitor out of Frequency

Tags: display

From what I can tell this hasn't been asked so I will

Me and a mate have just upgraded my hardware ( RAM and graphics card). When I plugged a monitor into the computer after the upgrades, this was displayed on the monitor:

```
hf:30khz- 60khz
vf: 50hz-75hz
current frequency
hf 64 vf 60
```

Now as you can see it's obvious that the current frequency is greater than the accepted frequency. The problem is that I do not know how to change these settings. Any ideas?

Benn

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for XP: In safe mode, you won't be able to change the resolution (or set refresh rates). Safe mode boots XP using a generic VGA driver, not the graphics driver you have loaded; this allows you to recover from video-drivers-gone-wrong type problems.
Instead of booting into safe mode, you'll need to boot into VGA mode. This isn't very well documented as far as I can tell; as best as I can recall, you'll need to do the following:

Hit F8 twice right after the computer boots. You'll see more options than you'll typically find in the normal F8 boot menu.

One of the options is VGA mode; select that option. XP will boot like normal, except it'll force the video card to boot at 640x480 with 4 colors @ 60hz. From there you can change the display settings however you want. You won't even need to reboot to get out of it.

Comment: I must thank you, this gave me so much trouble it's unreal

again many thanks